# Does there exist a real matrix $M$ so that its square is a $4\times4$ shift matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Does there exist a real matrix $M$ so that its square is a $4\times4$ shift matrix?

I was wondering if I can apply Cayley-Hamilton's theorem as I know that $\det(M)=0$ and $\mathrm{tr}(M^2)=0$. However, it doesn't seem that the theorem is manageable for $4\times4$ matrix... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If M exists, what would the rank of M have to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M^2$ is nilpotent, hence so is $M$. But if $M$ is nilpotent, then already $M^{\dim V}=0$ so that $(M^2)^2=0$ ...